# Randomly moving down a class hierarchy

Tags: java, hierarchy

I'm currently working on an "item drop" system, where items (and their properties) are randomly generated upon slaying an enemy. The current system I have is a hierarchy of classes, with **Item** being the root super class. Each class has specific properties common to all subclasses.

Ideally upon dropping an item, program will randomly select one property of the item and move down the hierarchy tree accordingly. For example, the process is as follows:

*Class* | *Randomly Selected Property determining path in tree:*

**Item | ItemType** -> **Equipable | EquipType** -> **Weapon | WeaponType** -> etc.

Example code:

```
abstract class Item 
{   
    private Type itemType;
    private String itemName;
    private int itemLevel;
    private Rarity itemRarity;
    private boolean questItem;
    private int itemPrice;

    public Item(String name)
    {
        itemType = Type.randomize();
        itemName = name;
        itemLevel = randomizeLevel(pLvl, eLvl);
        itemRarity = Rarity.randomize(bonus, pLvl, eLvl, iLvl);
        questItem = false;
        itemPrice = determinePrice();
    }
}
```

**Type** is an enum deciding the next level in the hierarchy. With this system, I dont know how to let the program determine the next level, and then proceed to it.

The problem I've run into is that I've realized in order for this to work, I have to work from the bottom of the hierarchy, up. Is there a way for me to work from the top-down, meaning I can start with a basic **Item** class and procedurally work my way down (using the methods I created to randomly select the properties).

If not, is there a specific way I should implement this system?

Comment: Why do you think you have to work from the bottom of the hierarchy up?

Comment: Sure why not. What's the problem?

Comment: @DavidK the problem I ran into was that, the property that determines the next level in the hierarchy is determined in the constructor of the class itself. Therefore, as it is now, I dont know how to move down the hierarchy once the next path is determined. I'll update the question

Comment: The code that chooses the random subclass can execute prior to calling the constructor of the object you're going to create. When you have randomly chosen a class, then you construct it. At least two of the answers are based on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all your enums from the enum class - the order is the order in which they are declared so if you declare them in hierarchy order, you can traverse the list however you want. The relevant oracle doc is here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/enumMembers.html

Comment: I see how this can be useful, but can you elaborate on how I would use this in my case?

Comment: @GBoggs The call gives you your entire hierarchy in hierarchy order. So, find your item in the list. Want to move up? move up the list from that index. Want to move down? Pick something further in the list. That way you get hierarchy-preserving randomization.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work your way from the top down, especially if the subclass selection depends on the choices made when constructing the superclass, then it's probably much better to favor composition over inheritance. So, if for `Item` you have `Type` specific information, you could make `Type` contain all the properties you could possibly want, including references to subsequent objects down this (conceptual) hierarchy.

At any point, of course, you can in addition make a small class hierarchy out of `Item`,  `Type`, and so on as long as you know before creating the object the specific subclass it should be. Otherwise, composition would be the only way to create your item in the fashion you describe.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a static method in each class that determines the 'next transition'(thinking of the package of 'items' as a tree.

So

```
// untested code

String nextClass = "Item";

// define a helper method

Class x = getClass(nextClass);

while( x.hasMore() == true )
{
    nextClass = x.getNextClass();
    x = getClass(nextClass);

} 
// reflection here on Class 'x' (whatever that is...)
```

Then you can use reflection to instantiate the last class.

This probably is a bad idea. But it would 'walk' a tree of well formed classes

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your goal, and try to reformulate:

- you have a top type: Item
- you have (or create now, or further perhaps ?) subclasses of Item, by adding some property: Equipable, then Weapon, etc.
- from top (Item), you want to random select a subclass (Equipable ? yes/no ? if yes => equip Type, etc.

What I suggest:

- dont break notion of subclass: a parent doesnt need to know by advance his children
- then take a class (1st: item, and so on), search subclasses by reflection
- select between children: at this point you must define how you categorize between children: any new variable, or any variable begining by a prefix. For example, you can define   final static int category_weapon=1; (or true, false, ...)
- then to iterate, you go from top, get children, get these static variables and value, and choose at random between these children, and do it again

Another way to caracterize: use Interfaces (weapon, equipable, ...): the benefit is you can then apply predefined method (for weapon, ...)

Cheaper : dont use any variable, just use the name of the children class to choose the next.

A good way to choose: define precisely what you'll do with these objects.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So are you just implying that I just have a method that will randomly select the first property (Type), then have a switch statement that will accordingly move down the hierarchy and randomly select the next one, so on and so forth until I reach one of the bottom nodes? Then at that point I simply create that object? Is this an efficient way, or the only way?

Comment: It is not surely the most efficient way, because of the reflection (but your program can do it once, and cache the information), and it is not the only way. The principal benefit is independence between classes: The day you create a dagger or a knife below weapon, that's done ! You dont have to maintain two parallel structures (one day, it wont be coherent).

Comment: Two things. 1)What do you mean by independence between classes? 2)What do you mean by create a dagger or knife below?

Comment: suppose your app uses weapon. next month you want to refine this with a new subclasses: knife. Then only subclass: nothing to do more to choose it randomly. Next month: other subclass of weapon: dagger: idem.